# Background video won't show in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added a background video header to the first page of my portfolio via vid.ly. It plays on a mobile device with no issues. However when I try to open it on my laptop in Chrome the video doesn't show. 
https://mcnamarakc.github.io/kathleenmcnamara/

If I have chrome dev tools open and refresh the page, the video will come through without issues.

```html
<video style="display: none" id="toggleDisplayFire" playsinline="playsinline" 
    autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted"loop="loop">
    <source src="https://vid.ly/7f4q4w" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#toggleDisplayFire').show();
 });
```

```
header video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Dev tools currently shows no errors, though sometimes I will get a Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) error. Video should start playing on page load and there is also an onclick function to switch between 2 different video backgrounds.

I'm open to hosting the video a different way but I haven't found another solution as the video files are huge! Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one

```
 <video style="display: none" id="toggleDisplayFire" playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted"
    loop="loop">
    <source src="https://d3fenhwk93s16g.cloudfront.net/7f4q4w/webm_480.webm?t=15629361515d28835787bda" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

you're putting video link of vid.ly player so I have replaced that link with actual video link.

Comment: That resolved it. Thank you so much! That was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This was supposed to be a comment but since i don't have enough rep i had to use an answer.

The reason it shows only when dev tools is open is probably because the screen is smaller. The responsiveness of your code may be the issue, see if you didn't set the video container to be hidden at certain screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're giving a wrong `src` attribute. This link `https://vid.ly/7f4q4w` returns a whole document and **not** the desired video file only. So, I recommend hosting the video by yourself.

Also, you can get the *real* link (`https://d3fenhwk93s16g.cloudfront.net/7f4q4w/webm_480.webm?t=15629357565d2881cc4384f`) for the video and use it but it **may** change in the future so you'll need a fallback for that.

Here's a working example for you with the real link :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggleDisplayFire').show();
});
```

```css
header video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video style="display: none" id="toggleDisplayFire" playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="https://d3fenhwk93s16g.cloudfront.net/7f4q4w/webm_480.webm?t=15629357565d2881cc4384f" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In the end, I really recommend you host your assets by yourself.

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score -1):

it's probably because the format of your video isn't a mp4 but something else.

Instead of

```html
<source src="https://vid.ly/7f4q4w" type="video/mp4">
```

try with

```html
<source src="https://vid.ly/7f4q4w" type="video/webm">
```